# Merge two data frames with identical columns into a data frame and combine one of the

Tags: r, merge

I have two dataframe of the same style and would like to merge them into a dataframe with the same columns whilst also combining one of the columns.

The two dataframes look like this:

```
    year variable
1  1968    2
2  1969    5
3  1970    <NA>
4  1971    <NA>
5  1972    <NA>

    year variable
1  1968    <NA>
2  1969    <NA>
3  1970    5
4  1971    7
5  1972    <NA>
```

and I would like to end up with a data frame that looks like this:

```
    year variable
1  1968    2
2  1969    5
3  1970    5
4  1971    7
5  1972    <NA>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [coalesce](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/coalesce.html) from dplyr:

```
df1 <- bind_cols(year = seq(1968, 1972, 1),
                 variable = c(2, 5, NA, NA, NA))

df2 <- bind_cols(year = seq(1968, 1972, 1),
                 variable = c(NA, NA, 5, 7, NA))


left_join(df1, df2, by='year') %>% 
  mutate(
    variable = coalesce(variable.x, variable.y)
  ) %>% 
  select(year, variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use dplyr package, and remove the NAs.
First you need to transform into proper NA

```
df1 <- data.frame(year = c(1968,1969,1970,1971,1972),
                 variable = c(2,5,'<NA>', '<NA>', '<NA>'))

df2 <- data.frame(year= c(1968,1969,1970,1971,1972),
                  variable = c('<NA>', '<NA>', 5, 7, '<NA>'))

library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(variable = ifelse(variable == "<NA>", NA, variable))
df2 <- df2 %>%
  mutate(variable = ifelse(variable == "<NA>", NA, variable))
df_m <- full_join(df1,df2) %>%
  na.omit(variable)
```

You can use merge, but I prefer the tidyverse.